# Taking the derivative of an integral 1

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

if I have an equation:
\begin{equation}
t = \int_{}^{} \frac{du}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln(u)+x_{0}\beta u)}
\end{equation}
where u is a function of time. Is it true that taking the derivative of both sides with respect to time:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}t = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{}^{} \frac{du}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln(u)+x_{0}\beta u)}
\end{equation}
Is it equal to?:
\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{1}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln(u) +x_{0}\beta u)} \frac{du}{dt}
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the role of $\;t\;$ in its definition? Just a name? Then how come you want to differentiate with respect of it?

Comment: No, t is in fact a variable time

Comment: I'm a little lost then: if that is true, then your second line is just what you actually wrote! Meaning, $\;\cfrac{dt}{dt}=1\;$ ...Why do you thing this equals the right hand without the integral sign, which doesn't seem to be depending on $\;t\;$ *at all* ?

Comment: The u is a function of time u(t).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is. If you have the equation $$t = \int f(u) du$$ and $u$ is a function of time $t$, we have $\frac{du}{dt} = u'$ and thus $du = u' dt$. Placing that to the equation we get $$t = \int f(u) u' dt.$$ Taking derivative with respect to $t$ on both sides is now easy and we get $$1 = f(u(t)) u'(t),$$ which is $$1 = f(u(t)) \frac{du}{dt}.$$